# Remove unwanted text in the select box label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, knockout.js

In my project the select box is loading dynamically using knockout js, In the label field i can see the unwanted text(select). so i want to remove it.

```
<label style="display: inline-block" data-bind="html: label, css: { 'fiori3-incomplete-labelsss': incompleteaa() &amp;&amp; $root.highlightIncompleteaaa(), 'pull-left': hinaaat(), 'required-attribute': requiredaa }, attr: { for: stdAttrCodeaaa }" for="9152"></label>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this 'Select' unwanted text fixed?

**If yes**, then you can just remove it using jQuery after page loaded.

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
   $('#TheLabel').text((index, text) => text.replace("Select", ""));
});
```

or any other similar script.

**If no**, then it is a dynamic text which you have to clean it up in back-end. There is no way for the front-end script to guess what the text is.